# angular2 filtering issue

Tags: arrays, filter, typescript, angular

I am trying to make a filter in angular2, i made an array of products like this:

`private products = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];`

and here is my filter pipe:

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({name:'filter'})

export class FilterPipe {
    transform(value, args) {
        if(!args[0]){
            return value;
        }
        else if (value) {
            return value.filter(item => {
                for (let key in item){
                    if((typeof item[key]==='string' || item[key] instanceof String) && (item[key].indexOf(args[0]) !== -1)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In my component I've added an `ul` element to display the products, and an `input` element to filter them:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterText">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#product of products | filter: filterText">
                        {{product}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

The problem when running this code is that it only works (filter) when typing the first letter, once more letters are entered it wont work. Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare each character of string from array with the entered text

```
'A'   => ('Apple') => 'A'.indexOf('A')   'p'.indexOf('A')   ...
'Ap'  => ('Apple') => 'A'.indexOf('Ap')  'p'.indexOf('Ap')  ... - always false
'App' => ('Apple') => 'A'.indexOf('App') 'p'.indexOf('App') ... - always false
```

I would change the pipe as follows:

```
@Pipe({name:'filter'})   
export class FilterPipe {
  transform(value, args) {
    if(!args[0]) return value;   
    return value.filter(item => item.indexOf(args[0]) > -1);
  }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/TpJ6Zu8QovWINqx04KUY?p=preview

**!!! It is Angular 2 Beta Version**

---

The code for **Angular RC** version will look like:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class FilterPipe {
  transform(value, term) {
    if (!term) return value;
    return value.filter(item => item.indexOf(term) > -1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I see the problem, thanks a lot, also with my filter code I changed the array to object and  it works